# Python Addon Error, Attribute Error: '_RestrictContex... no attribute 'view_layer'

Tags: python, add-on

i am currently scripting an addon for my Minecraft Rig Edit and i wante to try it out. But when i try activating the addon, an error message appears. It says:
Attribut Error: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'view_layer'

But i dont know how to fix this issue.

[image]

this is my report: error.

my script is based on two py files. One for properties and one for the rest : **init**:

```
import bpy
import os

from . import properties


#   -------
#   bl_info
#   -------


bl_info = {
    "name": "ThomasRig [BlueEvil Edit] Addon",
    "author": "BlueEvilGFX",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "User Interface Addon for ThomasRig [BlueEvil Edit]",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Thomas Blue"
    }  


#   ---------
#   operators
#   ---------


class Append_ThRigEdit(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "append.thomasrigblueeviledit"
    bl_label = "ThomasRig [BlueEvil Edit]"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

        script_directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)

        blendfile = os.path.join(script_directory, "RigTest.blend")
        section = "Collection"
        obj = "Rig [only append this]"
        filepath  = os.path.join(blendfile,section,obj)
        directory = os.path.join(blendfile,section)
        filename  = obj
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath,filename=filename,directory=directory,link=False,active_collection=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Append_ThRig(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "append.thomasrig"
    bl_label = "ThomasRig [Original]"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

        script_directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)

        blendfile = os.path.join(script_directory, "ThomasAnimations_Rig.blend")
        section = "Collection"
        obj = "Rig [only append this]"
        filepath  = os.path.join(blendfile,section,obj)
        directory = os.path.join(blendfile,section)
        filename  = obj
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath,filename=filename,directory=directory,link=False,active_collection=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class Append_Ribbon(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "append.ribbon" 
    bl_label = "append ribbon"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        try:
            return (bpy.context.active_object.get("rig_name") == 'ThomasBlueEditRig')
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return False

    def execute(self, context):
        script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

        script_directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)
        
        blendfile = os.path.join(script_directory,"accessories.blend")
        section = "Object"
        obj = "ribbon"
        filepath  = os.path.join(blendfile,section,obj)
        directory = os.path.join(blendfile,section)
        filename  = obj
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath,filename=filename,directory=directory,link=False,active_collection=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Append_Sashimono(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "append.sashimono"
    bl_label = "append sashimono"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        try:
            return (bpy.context.active_object.get("rig_name") == 'ThomasBlueEditRig')
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return False

    def execute(self, context):
        script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

        script_directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)

        blendfile = os.path.join(script_directory, "accessories.blend")
        section = "Object"
        obj = "sashimono"
        filepath  = os.path.join(blendfile,section,obj)
        directory = os.path.join(blendfile,section)
        filename  = obj
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath,filename=filename,directory=directory,link=False,active_collection=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Append_Torii(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "append.torii"
    bl_label = "append torii"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        try:
            return (bpy.context.active_object.get("rig_name") == 'ThomasBlueEditRig')
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return False

    def execute(self, context):
        script_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)

        script_directory = os.path.dirname(script_file)

        blendfile = os.path.join(script_directory, "accessories.blend")
        section = "Object"
        obj = "torii"
        filepath  = os.path.join(blendfile,section,obj)
        directory = os.path.join(blendfile,section)
        filename  = obj
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=filepath,filename=filename,directory=directory,link=False,active_collection=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}


# -------------
def menu_func(self, context):
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]
    my_icon = pcoll["BlueEvilGFX"]
    self.layout.menu("OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu", text = "Thomas Rig [BlueEvil Edit]", icon_value = my_icon.icon_id)
# -------------


#   -------
#   shift a
#   -------


class OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu"
    bl_label = "Append ThomasRig [BlueEvil Edit]"
    bl_options = bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout

        pcoll = preview_collections["main"]
        
        my_icon = pcoll["BlueEvilGFX"]
        layout.operator("append.thomasrigblueeviledit", icon_value = my_icon.icon_id)

        my_icon = pcoll["ThomasAnimations"]
        layout.operator("append.thomasrig", icon_value = my_icon.icon_id)


#   ----------
#   main panel
#   ----------
    

class RIG_UI(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Thomas [BlueEvil Edit] RIG Addon"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_Thomas_Blue"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Thomas Rig"
          
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        try:
            return (bpy.context.active_object.get("rig_name") == 'ThomasBlueEditRig')
        except (AttributeError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return False
              
    def draw(self, context):
            
        layout = self.layout        
        obj = context.object
        
        layout.label(text=" ThomasRig Edit - Addon", icon = "PROPERTIES")
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text = "made by BlueEvilGFX", icon = 'RIGHTARROW')
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "AntiLag", icon = "GRIP")
        if obj.get("AntiLag") == 1:
            row = layout.row()
            alignment = "CENTER"
            row.label(text = "(SmoothBend is disabled in the viewport)")


#   ----------
#   design panel
#   ---------- 


class Design_UI(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_Thomas_Blue"
    bl_label = "Design Settings"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_ThDesUI"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Thomas Rig"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}
 
    def draw(self, context):
            
        layout = self.layout       
        obj = context.object
        
        layout.label(text=" Design settings: ", icon = "SETTINGS")
               
        # female      
        box = layout.box()
        box.prop(obj, "FemaleMode", icon = "COMMUNITY")
        if obj.get('FemaleMode') == 1:
            if obj.get('FemaleArmR') == 0:
                icon = "LAYER_USED"
            else:
                icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
            split = box.split(factor = 0.5)
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "FemaleArmR", icon = icon, text = "F. Arms R")
            
            if obj.get('FemaleArmL') == 0:
                icon = "LAYER_USED"
            else:
                icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "FemaleArmL", icon = icon, text = "F. Arms L")
        
        # second Layer
        if obj.get('SecLayer') == 0:
            icon = "LAYER_USED"
        else: 
            icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
        box.prop(obj, "SecLayer", icon = icon)
        
        # finger
        if obj.get('Finger') == 0:
            box.prop(obj, "Finger", icon = "LAYER_USED")
        else:            
            split = box.split(factor = 0.5)
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "Finger", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                        
            if obj.get("FingerPlus") == 0:
                icon = "LAYER_USED"
            else: icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "FingerPlus", icon = icon)
        
        # smooth Bends
        if obj.get('SmoBends') == 0:
            icon = "LAYER_USED"
        else: 
            icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
        box.prop(obj, "SmoBends", icon = icon)
        
        # texture deform
        if obj.get('TextureDeform') == 0:
            icon = "LAYER_USED"
        else: 
            icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE"
        box.prop(obj, "TextureDeform", icon = icon)
        
        # armor
        box = layout.box()
        if obj.get('ArmorBool') == 0:
            box.prop(obj, 'ArmorBool', text = "Armor: Off", icon = "LAYER_USED")
        else: 
            split = box.split()
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, 'ArmorBool', text = "Armor: On", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
            
            cola = split.column(align = True)
            if obj.get('ArmorHideSettings') == 0:
                cola.prop(obj, 'ArmorHideSettings', text = "hide settings", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT")
                box.prop(obj, "ArmorTypeEnum", text = "Armor Type")
                
                split = box.split(factor = 0.75)
                col = split.column(align = True)
                
                col.label(text = "select your armor here", icon = "OUTLINER_OB_ARMATURE")
                
                if obj.get("ArmorTypeEnum")  == 0:

                    # normal armor
                    col.prop(obj, "ArmorHelmetEnum", text = "Helmet")
                    col.prop(obj, "ArmorChestplateEnum", text = "Chestplate")
                    col.prop(obj, "ArmorLeggingsEnum", text = "Leggings")
                    col.prop(obj, "ArmorBootsEnum", text = "Boots") 
                    
                    col = split.column(align = True)
                    col.label(text = "")
                    
                    if obj.get("ArmorHelmetEnum") is 4:
                        col.prop(obj, "helmet_color", text = "")
                    else: col.label(text = "")
                    
                    if obj.get("ArmorChestplateEnum") is 4:
                        col.prop(obj, "chestplate_color", text = "")
                    else: col.label(text = "")
                    
                    if obj.get("ArmorLeggingsEnum") is 4:
                        col.prop(obj, "leggings_color", text = "")
                    else: col.label(text = "")
                    
                    if obj.get("ArmorBootsEnum") is 4:
                        col.prop(obj, "boots_color", text = "")
                    else: col.label(text = "")

                elif obj.get("ArmorTypeEnum") == 1:

                    # samurai armor 
                    col.label(text= "Does not work in female mode!")               
                    split = box.split(align = True)
                    col1 = split.column(align = True)
                    col2 = split.column(align = True)                    
                    col3 = split.column(align = True)
                   
                    if obj.get("SamuraiHelmet") == 1:
                        col1.prop(obj, "SamuraiHelmet", text = "Helmet", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else:
                        col1.prop(obj, "SamuraiHelmet", text = "Helmet", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")
                    if obj.get("SamuraiChestplate") == 1:
                        col2.prop(obj, "SamuraiChestplate", text = "Chestplate", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else: 
                        col2.prop(obj, "SamuraiChestplate", text = "Chestplate", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")
                    if obj.get("SamuraiSkirt") == 1:
                        col3.prop(obj, "SamuraiSkirt", text = "Skirt", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else:
                        col3.prop(obj, "SamuraiSkirt", text = "Skirt", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")

                    if obj.get("SamuraiArmorCustomColor") == 0:
                        box.prop(obj, "SamuraiArmorCustomColor", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "custom color")   
                    else:
                        box.prop(obj, "SamuraiArmorCustomColor", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "custom color")
                        split = box.split(align = False)
                        col1 = split.column(align = True)
                        col2 = split.column(align = True)

                        col1.prop(obj, "SamuraiArmorColor", text = "")
                        col2.prop(obj, "SamuraiArmorValue", text = "Value", slider = True) 

                elif obj.get("ArmorTypeEnum") == 2:

                    # cultist armor
                    col.label(text = "Does not work in female mode!")
                    split = box.split(align = True)
                    col1 = split.column(align = True)
                    col2 = split.column(align = True)                    
                    col3 = split.column(align = True) 
                    col4 = split.column(align = True) 

                    if obj.get("CultistHelmet") == 1:
                        col1.prop(obj, "CultistHelmet", text = "Helmet", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else: 
                        col1.prop(obj, "CultistHelmet", text = "Helmet", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")
                    if obj.get("CultistChestplate") == 1:
                        col2.prop(obj, "CultistChestplate", text = "Chestplate", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else: 
                        col2.prop(obj, "CultistChestplate", text = "Chestplate", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")     
                    if obj.get("CultistSkirt") == 1:
                        col3.prop(obj, "CultistSkirt", text = "Skirt", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else: 
                        col3.prop(obj, "CultistSkirt", text = "Skirt", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")
                    if obj.get("CultistBannerFront") == 1:
                        col4.prop(obj, "CultistBannerFront", text = "Banner Front", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
                    else: 
                        col4.prop(obj, "CultistBannerFront", text = "Banner Front", icon = "RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")

                    if obj.get("CultistCustomColor") == 0:
                        box.prop(obj, "CultistCustomColor", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "custom color")   
                    else:
                        split = box.split()
                        col1 = split.column()
                        col2 = split.column()

                        col1.prop(obj, "CultistCustomColor", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "custom color")
                        col2.prop(obj, "CultistColor", text = "")
                    if obj.get("CultistClothSim") == 0:
                        box.prop(obj, "CultistClothSim", text = "Cloth Simulation", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                    else:
                        box.prop(obj, "CultistClothSim", text = "Cloth Simulation", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
        
            else:
                cola.prop(obj, 'ArmorHideSettings', text = "hide settings", icon = "RIGHTARROW")
            

#   ----------
#   extra panel
#   ----------

class Extra_UI(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_Thomas_Blue"
    bl_label = "Extra Features"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_ThExtUI"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Thomas Rig"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}
 
    def draw(self, context):
            
        layout = self.layout       
        obj = context.object
        
        layout.label(text=" Extra Features: ", icon = "GP_SELECT_POINTS")
            
        # blush
        box = layout.box()
        if obj.get("Blush") == 0:
            box.prop(obj, "Blush", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "Blush: Off")
        else:
            split = box.split()
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "Blush", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "Blush: On")
            
            col = split.column(align = True)
            if obj.get("BlushHideSettings") == 0:
                col.prop(obj, "BlushHideSettings", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "hide settings")
                box.prop(obj, "BlushIntensity", text = "blush intensity", slider = True)
                box.prop(obj, "BlushTrashhold", text = "blush skin trashhold", slider = True)
            else:
                col.prop(obj, "BlushHideSettings", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "hide settings")
                
        # ribbon
        box = layout.box()
        if obj.get("Ribbon") == 0:
            box.prop(obj, "Ribbon", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "Ribbon: Off")
        else:
            split = box.split()
            col1 = split.column(align = False)
            col1.prop(obj, "Ribbon", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "Ribbon: On")
            
            col2 = split.column(align = False)
            if obj.get("RibbonHideSettings") == 0:
                col2.prop(obj, "RibbonHideSettings", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "hide settings")
                                
                # ribbon hair bow   
                if obj.get("RibbonHairBow") == 0:
                    box.prop(obj, "RibbonHairBow", text = "Hair Bow: Off", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                else: 
                    split = box.split()
                    col = split.column(align = False)
                    col.prop(obj, "RibbonHairBow", text = "Hair Bow: On", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                    
                    col = split.column(align = False)
                    col.prop(obj, "RibbonHairBowColor", text = "")
                    
                # ribbon bow tie
                if obj.get("RibbonBowTie") == 0:
                    box.prop(obj, "RibbonBowTie", text = "Bow Tie: Off", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                else:
                    split = box.split()
                    col = split.column(align = False)
                    col.prop(obj, "RibbonBowTie", text = "Bow Tie: On", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                    
                    col = split.column(align = False)
                    col.prop(obj, "RibbonBowTieColor", text = "")
            else:
                col2.prop(obj, "RibbonHideSettings", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "hide settings")
        
           
        # scarf
        box = layout.box()        
        if obj.get("Scarf") == 0:
            box.prop(obj, "Scarf", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "Scarf: Off")
        else:
            split = box.split()
            col = split.column(align = True)
            col.prop(obj, "Scarf", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "Scarf: On")
            
            col = split.column(align = True)
            if obj.get("ScarfHideSettings") == 0:
                col.prop(obj, "ScarfHideSettings", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "hide settings")
                
                # scarf color
                if obj.get("ScarfCS") == 0:
                    box.prop(obj, "ScarfCS", text = "custom color", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                else:
                    split = box.split()
                    col1 = split.column(align = False)
                    col1.prop(obj, "ScarfCS", text = "custom color", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                    
                    col2 = split.column(align = False)
                    if obj.get("ScarfColorSettings") == 0:
                        col2.prop(obj, "ScarfColorSettings", text = "1 or 2 Color", icon = "EVENT_A")
                        box.prop(obj, "ScarfColor", text = "")
                    else:
                        #split = box.split()
                        col2.prop(obj, "ScarfColorSettings", text = "1 or 2 Color", icon = "EVENT_B")
                        split = box.split()
                        col1 = split.column(align = False)
                        col2 = split.column(align = False)
                        col1.prop(obj, "ScarfColorA", text = "")
                        col2.prop(obj, "ScarfColorB", text = "")
                    
                # scarf lattice
                if obj.get("ScarfLattice") == 0:
                    box.prop(obj, "ScarfLattice", text = " scarf lattice", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                else:  
                    split = box.split()
                    col = split.column(align = True)
                    col.prop(obj, "ScarfLattice", text = "lattice", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                    
                    col = split.column(align = True)
                    if obj.get("ScarfHideLattice") == 0:
                        col.prop(obj, "ScarfHideLattice", text = "hide lattice", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                    else:
                        col.prop(obj, "ScarfHideLattice", text = "hide lattice", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                if obj.get("ScarfSubdivision") == 1:
                    box.prop(obj, "ScarfSubdivision", text = "sundivision: on", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                else:
                    box.prop(obj, "ScarfSubdivision", text = "subdivision: off", icon ="LAYER_USED")
            else: 
                col.prop(obj, "ScarfHideSettings", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "hide settings")
        
        # head gear
        box = layout.box()
        if obj.get("HeadGear") == 0:
            box.prop(obj, "HeadGear", icon = "LAYER_USED", text = "Head Gear: Off")
        else:
            split = box.split()
            col = split.column(align = False)
            col.prop(obj, "HeadGear", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE", text = "Head Gear: On")
            
            col = split.column(align = False)
            if obj.get("HeadGearHideSettings") == 0:
                col.prop(obj, "HeadGearHideSettings", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "hide settings")
                box.prop(obj, "HeadGearEnum", text = "head gear")
                
                # hat
                if obj.get("HeadGearEnum") == 2:
                    split = box.split()
                    col1 = split.column(align = False)
                    if obj.get("HatSub") == 1:
                        col1.prop(obj, "HatSub", text = "Subdivision", icon = "LAYER_ACTIVE")
                    else:                  
                        col1.prop(obj, "HatSub", text = "Subdivision", icon = "LAYER_USED")
                    col2 = split.column(align = False)
                    col2.prop(obj, "HatColor", text = "")

            else:
                col.prop(obj, "HeadGearHideSettings", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "hide settings")

        # append accessories
        box = layout.box()
        if obj.get("ShowAppendAccessories") == False:
            box.prop(obj, "ShowAppendAccessories", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "append additional objects:")     
        else:
            box.prop(obj, "ShowAppendAccessories", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "append additional objects:")

            split = box.split(align = True)
            col1 = split.column(align = True)
            col2 = split.column(align = True)
            
            col1.operator("append.ribbon", text = "ribbon")
            
            # samurai accesories
            if obj.get("ShowSamuraiAccessories") == False:
                col2.prop(obj, "ShowSamuraiAccessories", icon = "RIGHTARROW", text = "show samurai appends")
            else:
                col2.prop(obj, "ShowSamuraiAccessories", icon = "DOWNARROW_HLT", text = "show samurai appends")
                col2.operator("append.torii", text = "torii")
                col2.operator("append.sashimono", text = "sashimono")

                       
#   ------------
#   (un)register
#   ------------


classes = (
            RIG_UI,
            Design_UI,
            Material_UI,
            Pose_UI,
            Face_UI,
            Extra_UI,
            OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu,
            Append_Ribbon,
            Append_Sashimono,
            Append_Torii,
            Append_ThRigEdit,
            Append_ThRig,
          )

#register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

preview_collections = {}

def register():
    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    my_icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")
    pcoll.load("BlueEvilGFX", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "BlueEvilGFX.png"), 'IMAGE')
    pcoll.load("ThomasAnimations", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "ThomasAnimations.png"), 'IMAGE')
    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.append(menu_func)
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu")   
  
def unregister():
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.remove(menu_func)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

No Property file here because the body is limited to 30000 characters.

sadly i dont know how to fix this issue. If someone got also tips for me how to improve the script I would be also happy about it. But first I would like to fix this problem.
Thanks for your help

Comment: When an addon is registering it has restricted context... most operators are not going to work  .  This is why see test calls in the `if __name__ == "__main__": ` clause to make test calls. Sum up remove `bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="OBJECT_MT_ShiftA_submenu") ` from register method.

Comment: That's an excellent answer. This really helped me. Thank you very much! Btw, how can I accept this as a valid answer because it's just a comment your were writing.